# android save checkedtextview check

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have an listview with an checkedtextview in each view, all of my items are being manipulated through a database, everything works, but i cant save the checked state of list items, i have a drawable set for each click, but i dont know how to save it if i start another activity, An answer with code would be highly appreciated, thanks
PLEASE HELP!

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckedTextView tt = (CheckedTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkedview1);
                    if (!tt.isChecked()) {
                    tt.setChecked(true);

                    tt.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.checkedbox);
                    } else {
                    tt.setChecked(false);
                    tt.setCheckMarkDrawable(R.drawable.nullbox);
                    }
        }

    });
```

Here is the xml for my listview and my checkedtextview

```
<CheckedTextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
  android:id="@+id/checkedview1" 
  android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
  android:paddingRight="20dip" 
  android:paddingTop="10dip"
  android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
  android:gravity="center_vertical"  
  android:checkMark="@drawable/nullbox"
  android:textSize = "18sp"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:listSelector="#ef0000"
```

>

And my listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="404dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff" />
```

this is the adapter i use to load my list
            checklistDB.open();
        c = checklistDB.getAllTasks();

```
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        String task = c.getString(1);
        adapter.add(task);
    }
    checklistDB.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    class NormalListHolder {
        ImageView check;
    }

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    NormalListHolder normalListHolder;

    public CheckAdapter(Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                    null);
            normalListHolder = new NormalListHolder();
            convertView.setTag(normalListHolder);
        } else {
            normalListHolder = (NormalListHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        normalListHolder.favoriteTag.setId(position);
        normalListHolder.favoriteTag
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (favoriteStatus.get(v.getId())) { // favorite
                            favoriteStatus.set(v.getId(), false);
                            normalListHolder.favoriteTag.setImageSrc();
                        } else {
                            favoriteStatus.set(v.getId(), true);
                            normalListHolder.favoriteTag.setImageSrc();
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I edit from my code, but I'm not sure if it works(I edit it not very careful), I will explain what I do below:

1 create a ArrayList which saved the item status (or when you scroll the listview the checkbox will confused)

```
ArrayList<Boolean> favoriteStatus = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

2 create a new Adpater, and make a **holder** in it, the holder bind the views in listitem together.

3 setTag to the listitem by holder

4 when click on it, look for the status in statusArray, and put proper status to the view, then notifyDatasetChange(if it is a checkbox, maybe don't need, because I use a imageview here) you also can do update database or other actions here

sorry for my pool English, hope that it can help you